# NSDateFormatter, am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to print out the date in a certain format:

```
NSDate *today = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss"];
NSString *dateStr = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
```

If the iPhone is set to 24 hour time, this works fine, if on the other hand the user has set it to 24 hour time, then back to AM/PM (it works fine until you toggle this setting) then it appends the AM/PM on the end even though I didn't ask for it:

```
20080927030337 PM
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug with firmware 2.1?

Edit 1: Made description clearer

Edit 2 workaround: It turns out this is a bug, to fix it I set the AM and PM characters to "":

```
[dateFormatter setAMSymbol:@""];
[dateFormatter setPMSymbol:@""];
```

Comment: Getting exactly the same problem -- pleased to see that I'm not going crazy!

Comment: Just a note, if you are using the setAM/PM methods there will still be an extra space in the string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the code you posted on both the simulator and a phone with the 2.1 firmware and 24-hour time set to off, I never had an AM/PM appended to dateStr when I do:

```
NSLog(@"%@", dateStr);
```

Are you doing anything else with dateStr that you didn't post here? How are you checking the value?

**Follow up**

> Try turning the am/pm setting on then off. I didn't have the problem either, until I did that. I am printing it out the same way you are.

Okay, I see it when I do this also. It's gotta be a bug. I recommend you [file a bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com/) and just check for and filter out the unwanted characters in the meantime.

Comment: try turning the am/pm setting on then off. I didn't have the problem either, until I did that. I am printing it out the same way you are.

Comment: This answer is not the solution - huyz answer correctly answers this - it's a bug with NSDateFormatter

Answer (score 32):

The reason for this behaviour is Locale, It sets the correct Locale.

Set the local of your **NSDateFormatter** to **en_US_POSIX** will fix this.
It works for both 24-hour and 12 hour format.

`On iPhone OS, the user can override the default AM/PM versus 24-hour time setting (via Settings > General > Date & Time > 24-Hour Time), which causes NSDateFormatter to rewrite the format string you set.` From [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1)

Try this,

```
NSDate *today = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss"];
NSString *dateStr = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
```

Comment: Thank you. I spent 5 solid hours to encounter this and because it always give me a time format string with "a.m / p.m" causing my API request fails because of &timeRequest string value with space!

Answer (score 14):

Here's the explanation of the iPhone SDK bug (also still there in 3.1 beta SDK)

> First, a little background on the iPhone user interface.  When iPhone
>   users change their region format between, say, “United States” and
>   “France”, the users’ “24-Hour Time” setting is automatically switched
>   to the mode that is most prevalent in that region.  In France, that
>   would set 24-Hour Time to “ON”, and in the U.S., that would set it to
>   “OFF”.  The users can then manually override that setting and that’s
>   where trouble starts.
>
> The problem comes from NSDateFormatter somehow “getting stuck” in the
>   12 or 24-hour time mode that the user has manually selected.  So if a
>   French user manually selects 12-hour mode,  and the application
>   requested NSDateFormatter to output time with the 24-hour format
>   “HHmm”, it would actually receive time in a 12-hour format, e.g.
>   “01:00 PM”, as if the application had instead requested “hhmm aa”. 
>   The reverse would happen if a US user manually selected 24-hour mode:
>   outputting time with the 12-hour  format “hhmm aa” would actually get
>   you time in the 24-hour format instead, e.g. “17:00″.

More details and a possible workaround can be found on this [blog](http://multinc.com/2009/09/27/iphone-sdk-time-bug-for-international-users/).

Comment: I've confirmed this on a test device. Change international setting to United Kingdom. Set Date & Time 24 hour time to off to reproduce in your apps.  Workaround for me was @DenNukem response below of setting locale to en_US for the date formatter.

Comment: @earnshavian u saved my life!! My client recently came across this problem, which I cannot reproduce because I was using US region! I tried setting to other regions all were working fine, until I saw your comment, it was UK region causing the problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9):

Setting locale on date formatter to en_US fixes the problem for me:

```
    NSDateFormatter * f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [f setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
    f.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
    f.calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
    f.locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease];
```

I'm not sure if adding the calendar is also needed, but this works well.

Comment: I didn't change the calendar, and after doing my operations, I wanted to change the date formatter back to the user's locale, so I did f.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale]. That worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is the solution .

```
NSDateFormatter *df =[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
        NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];

[df setLocale: usLocale];

[usLocale release];

 NSDate *documento_en_Linea =[[[NSDate alloc] init]autorelease];

documento_en_Linea=[df dateFromString:@"2010-07-16 21:40:33"];

[df release];

        NSLog(@"fdocumentoenLineaUTC:%@!",documento_en_Linea);


//ouput  
     fdocumentoenLineaUTC:2010-07-16 09:40:33 p.m. -0500!
```

Answer (score 1):

For those finding this question who want to use NSDateFormatter to parse 24-hour time and are hitting this bug, using NSDateComponents to parse dates and times which have a known format sidesteps this issue:

```
NSString *dateStr = @"2010-07-05";
NSString *timeStr = @"13:30";

NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
components.year = [[dateStr substringToIndex:4] intValue];
components.month = [[dateStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(5, 2)] intValue];
components.day = [[dateStr substringFromIndex:8] intValue];
components.hour = [[timeStr substringToIndex:2] intValue];
components.minute = [[timeStr substringFromIndex:3] intValue];

NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

[components release];
[calendar release];
```

Answer (score 0):

This should also work (I am seeing some bizzare results though).

```
-(NSString*)lowLevTime:(NSString*)stringFormat {
    char buffer[50];
    const char *format = [stringFormat UTF8String];
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    time(&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
    strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), format, timeinfo);
    return [NSString  stringWithCString:buffer encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: try `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddhhmmss"];` for 12 hour format (note the lowercase `hh`).

It's been a frustrating topic because so many websites indicate to use `HH` for hours (including the official Apple documentation), but that sets it to 24 hour format, whereas `hh` uses 12 hour format.  See http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns for more details.

As a bonus, note that you can also use `KK` or `kk` for hour of the day format, which will likely be off by one.

Update:
I was recently looking at NSLocale (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and it would seem that you can use autoupdatingCurrentLocale to apply changes made from within the app to the Locale. The upshot of this is that even if the phone is set to use a 24 hour clock (like when you switched to France), you can make a 12/24 toggle for the app that won't impact any other apps on the phone, or require you to leave the app to make the change.