# text field with multiple dots and comma

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a textfield that I can put as many dots and commas as I want, how can I limit the textfield to only 1 dot or 1 comma, I am only using numbers in the textfield so I only want the user to enter it once.

Comment: whats the target platform (OSX, iOS)?

Comment: It is IOS, sorry forgot to put that

Comment: ok, OSX has a NSTextField with number format... ;-)

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709450/uitextfield-format-in-xx-xx-xxx