# UITextField date formatting

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I have a `UITextfield` set up where users can fill in their date of birth in `mm-dd-yyyy`. But what I want is when the user fills in their date of birth that it replaces the m,d or y character with the number. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Why dont you use UIDatePicker instead?

Comment: Look at `UITextField` delegate. But as suggested by @AnoopVaidya, a `UIDatePicker` would be more interesting.

Comment: it more appropriate to use UIDatePicker for birthdate instead of UITextField...

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITextField format in xx-xx-xxx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709450/uitextfield-format-in-xx-xx-xxx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Answer :

Go with `UIDatePicker`.

---

Second Answer:

[UITextField format in xx-xx-xxx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709450/uitextfield-format-in-xx-xx-xxx)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a placeholder "mm-dd-yyyy" which does not - as usual, hide when starting to type but hides letter for letter?
I think this isn't how iOS works (anyhow you should use NSDatePicker), but if you have a reason why you do so you can use an UITextfield with an NSAttributedString (because of placeholder color) and update it accordingly to input events.