# Wrong Date from string returns from formatter! Why?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have problem with NSDateFormatter
I converting date from picker in one view

```
`NSDateFormatter *output = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[output setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[output setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[output setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];    
NSString *StringToSend = [output stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
```

`
then send string to other nib

where converting it back with that code

```
`NSDateFormatter *inputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[inputFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[inputFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate *formatterDate = [inputFormatter dateFromString:StringFromOtherView];
NSLog(@"%@", formatterDate);`
```

and it's return wrong date 
sending 2011-09-26 01:02:49
geting  2011-09-25 22:02:49 +0000

what is wrong?

Comment: Why are you setting MediumStyle and then short style?  And then specifying an explicit date format.  Looks like output from the Department of Redundancy Department.

Comment: "Department of Redundancy Department". Hilarious!

Answer (score 5):

Because:

1. When you `NSLog()` an `NSDate`, it *always* logs it in GMT
2. You live in a timezone that's three hours ahead of of GMT.  Thus, 1:02 am for you is 22:02 pm (of the previous day) in GMT.

Comment: +1 for Great Answer..! Day by day I am becoming a fan of yours. I look up to you and if I can be as knowledgable as you one day then I think I will achieve great success :]

Answer (score 0):

Include the timezone on your date format string.

Comment: But see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformater-locale-feature).  You should set the locale in addition to setting the timezone.

Answer (score 0):

```
 + (NSDate*) dateFromString:(NSString*)aStr
 {

  if (aStr.length == 10) {
    aStr = [aStr stringByAppendingFormat:@" 00:00:00"];
 }
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
   dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
    NSLog(@"strdate %@", aStr);
    NSDate   *aDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:aStr];
    NSLog(@"date = %@",aDate);
    [dateFormatter release];
    return aDate;
```

}