# How to format NSDate to NSString?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4, nsdate

I have an date string which looks like this:

```
2011-10-01 08:45:34 +0000
```

How can I format it with NSDate? Thanks :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this method in [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
- (NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)string
```

an example

```
dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

NSLocale *en_US = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:en_US];
[en_US release];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:-60*60*7]];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

[dateFormatter release];
```

Comment: Important:  If you want the date to always display the same, [explicitly assign the local of the formatter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformater-locale-feature).