# Convert date format in objc

Tags: iphone, objective-c, datetime

The following is the code I am using to change the date from one format to another.  In the following code `child.dob` is in `NSDate` as `yyyy-MM-dd` format  I want to change to `MMM dd, yyyy` format  I am able to change the date format however I am getting a warning message here .  Please help me to convert date without warning.. Thanks in advance.

```
  NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:child.dob]; 
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];
    dobLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

This is the warning message I am getting:
:801: warning: incompatible Objective-C types 'struct NSDate *', expected 'struct NSString *' when passing argument 1 of 'dateFromString:

Comment: What is the warning you're getting?

Comment: `NSDate` do not know the format they are displayed, they just hold a date object with a timezone. You can use `NSDateFormatter` to create a `NSString` form a `NSDate` object. If you **`NSLog`** a `NSDate` object it will always display the full date with timezone.

Comment: :801: warning: incompatible Objective-C types 'struct NSDate *', expected 'struct NSString *' when passing argument 1 of 'dateFromString:' from distinct Objective-C type  this is the warning I am getting

Comment: The warning is becaue in this line:
`NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:child.dob]; `
You are passing an NSDate, when it expects a NSString.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I agree with you Tudorizer.  I need to know how to get rid of this date conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, you use NSDateFormatter dateFromString to convert an NSDate object to a displayable string.  Use NSDateFormatter stringFromDate to go the other way.

If you use NSLog on an NSDate then under the covers it does a `description` call which presents a fixed format.  However, `description` should not be used for "real" work since the format presented is not rigorously defined and could change at any time.

Note that there is a ["feature"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformater-locale-feature) of NSDateFormatter in that it can erroneously (in my mind) add or remove an AM/PM value based on phone settings, even when you have explicitly specified the format to NSDateFormatter.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  This is what I need Daniel one date format to another I tried like this: NSDate *date = child.dob; 
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];  still I am getting error can you guide me to change date from one format to another.

Comment: In your original post, you never use the second date format.  The date isn't going to format itself.

Comment: Sorry Daniel,  I forgot to included one more line I have edited my code please help.

Comment: @DilipRajkumar -- Should work, if child.dob is an NSString in the yyyy-MM-dd format.  Of course, you're missing the release of your date formatter, but that just causes a leak -- it won't cause the code to fail.  But you continue to fail to say what's not working -- you haven't posted any error messages, etc.  You're going to get dinged if you don't start providing better information.

Comment: In my post I told that child.dob is a NSDate.  its in the format yyyy-MM-dd  I need the same date as MMM dd, yyyy format and I am able to get it by above code.  However that is not the correct way because I am trying to convert a NSDate to NSDate using stringFromDate so I need to know the right procedure.  If I try dateFromString I am getting null..The following is the error message i am getting :801: warning: incompatible Objective-C types 'struct NSDate *', expected 'struct NSString *' when passing argument 1 of 'dateFromString:

Comment: Then YOY do you use dateFromString to convert an NSDate to an NSDate?  Is the name of the function a clue, maybe?  (BTW, NSDate objects are not in any "format" -- they are numerical values.  If you want a particular format you use stringFromDate.)

Comment: An NSDate isn't "in" any given format; strictly speaking, it is just a wrapper around an offset from from fixed date.