# Having trouble with date formatter for string date 2011-11-25T21:17:49-05:00

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have tried a few variations of the date formats suggested in other threads, but I can't get the string date of "2011-11-25T21:17:49-05:00" to convert correctly, I always end up with a nil NSDate:

```
stringDate = @"2011-11-25T21:17:49-05:00";
NSLog(@"The String: %@", stringDate);
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"];
NSDate *theDate = [formatter dateFromString:stringDate];
NSLog(@"The Date: %@", theDate);
```

Produces the following output:

```
2011-11-26 00:01:35.592 Octain3[21779:11603] The String: 2011-11-25T21:17:49-05:00
2011-11-26 00:01:43.298 Octain3[21779:11603] The Date: (null)
```

I can get it to give me an NSDate if I loose the "-05:00" but even then I seem to get the wrong time zone:

```
stringDate = @"2011-11-25T21:17:49";
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
theDate = [formatter dateFromString:stringDate];
NSLog(@"The Date: %@", theDate);
```

Output:

```
2011-11-26 00:01:50.554 Octain3[21779:11603] The Date: 2011-11-26 02:17:49 +0000
```

Comment: what happens if you use an initial stringDate of `@"2011-11-25T21:17:49 -0500` (and put a space between `ss` and `ZZZ` in your formatter)?

Comment: What's the origin of this string? Do you have any control over it?

Comment: The string appears to be a standard "internet date" format, used by many servers.  If it is produced by a server there's likely little or no control over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting to see the other answers agree. I went the route of assuming you could not control the format of the string so I came up with an alternative that separates the timezone and parses it separately. But most importantly it assumes you cannot change the format of the string you are getting.

```
NSString *stringDate = @"2011-11-25T21:17:49-05:00";

NSString *timeZoneString = [stringDate substringFromIndex:19];
NSString *dateString = [stringDate substringToIndex:19];
int zoneOffset = (60 * 60 * timeZoneString.intValue);

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:zoneOffset];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
NSDate *theDate = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Comment: Parsing works with both yours and Michael's suggested formatters. It seems I can just leave off the timezone, as all the data in the server seems to be the same zone (server time). However, I am puzzled by the output. When I log it with NSLog(@"The Date: %@", parsedDate); It's saying the parsed time is 2011-11-26 02:17:49 +0000 (also in Michael's output. I noticed the same thing with output if I used theDate = [NSDate date];

Comment: That's because NSDate internally saves as a GMT. You can see in the output +0000 means no offset from GMT. If you use a second NSDateFormatter, which will default to the system time zone, to output the date as a string it will show your correct local time. This is the correct usage of NSDate.

Answer (score 2):

NSDateFormatter can't handle the timezone offset field with a `:` in it.  You need to remove that (by manipulating the string) before processing the date.  If you don't include the timezone field then the date will be read in the current timezone, unless you set the timezone of the NSDateFormatter.

And remember that you should always set a ["safe" local](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6735644/581994) when interpreting a fixed-format string, or else your app can be fouled up by the phone's locale setting.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on my comment, I just changed that code in a small test project of my own.

Code like this:

```
NSString * stringDate = @"2011-11-25T21:17:49 -0500";
NSLog(@"The String: %@", stringDate);

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
NSDate *theDate = [formatter dateFromString:stringDate];
NSLog(@"The Date: %@", theDate);
[formatter release];
```

Produces this:

```
2011-11-26 00:37:27.082 TestingiPhone[43505:f803] The String: 2011-11-25T21:17:49 -0500
2011-11-26 00:37:41.006 TestingiPhone[43505:f803] The Date: 2011-11-26 02:17:49 +0000
```

I think you just need to tweak a couple inputs and you'll be okay!