# Localization and date

Tags: objective-c, date, localization

I can't figure out why the next piece of code only works when I set the Region Format to United States.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:currentFeedPubDate];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

Otherwise it returns "(null)".

Can anyone help me find out why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Krizz already noted, the issue is that the localized names won't match. For example, if you feed it a date like `Sun, 15 Jan 2012 22:52:00 GMT+1` and the phone is currently set to German, it won't recognize `Sun` as it would look for an abbreviation of a German weekday name but won't find one.

If you know in which locale format the input string will be you can (and need to) force the locale on your date formatter like this:

```
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease]];
```

Comment: Thank you both for your explaintation. That's what I didn't understand before.

Answer (score 2):

What is your `currentFeedPubDate`? Probably it is something like `Sun, 15 Jun 2012 22:31:30 GMT+1`, right?

Now, note that while in United States locale `MMM` will be something like `Jan` (from English January), in Polish locale it will be `Sty` (from Polish Styczeń, name for January) and thus your string won't match.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, there is a problem you may encounter if someone toggles the 12/24 setting in their phone's preferences.  This problem is discussed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformater-locale-feature).

Comment: Why do we let users do what the hell they want... Thanks for the info, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Yeah, I never have figured out what good users are -- they just seem to cause trouble.