# strange Date formatter issue in iPhone device

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to convert date from string ,

Below is my code,

```
str_date = @"04/16/2011 00:00:00 AM";

NSDateFormatter *dtF = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dtF setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];

NSDate *d = [dtF dateFromString:str_date];


NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:d]; 
[dateFormat release];

return dateString;
```

Here the issue is, in the simulator it is working fine and converts string to date and date to string, but with Device, it is not able to convert **string to date**

In iPod retina it is not showing the date, but with iPhone 3gs it shows the date

Please help me what wrong  I have made ?

Comment: You might be running into [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformater-locale-feature) -- the phone behaves oddly if the 12/24 hour setting in Settings is in conflict with your locale.

Comment: I have resolved issue , I just removed the time from the string and then removed the HH:mm:ss a , it's nowworking, I thing there were some issues similar as informed by Hot Licks.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace this line like this

```
NSDateFormatter *dtF = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; [dtF setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
```

Because HH use for 24 Hour format and hh use for 12 hour format...