# NSDateFormatter not working with 4:15:00 PM

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

How do I convert "4:15:00 PM" to an NSDate? Below is the code I have:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss aa"];
NSDate *date =  [df dateFromString:@"4:15:00 PM"];

NSLog(@"date: %@",date);//outputs: 1970-01-01 17:15:00 +0000
//should output: 1970-01-01 16:15:00 +0000
```

UPDATE: I updated based on responses and I am still having the incorrect show:

```
NSLog(@"date: %@",[df stringFromDate:date]);//outputs: 12:15:00 PM
//should output: 4:15:00 PM
```

**The question is why does the time change from 4:15:00 PM 12:15:00 PM.**

Comment: NSLog of an NSDate displays in UTC.

Comment: And be aware of the [12/24 gotcha](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6613110/581994).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, this is correct.

However, the debugger and `NSLog` **display** the time in GMT.

If you want to display local time, use a `NSDateFormatter` and `stringFromDate`.

**Update:**
Your date formatter format is also set incorrectly.

It should be:  `[df setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss aa"];` since you are using a 12 hour clock.

Comment: Umm, it is outputting the correct time now.  Just change the format if you want it to display differently.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of your locale.

`NSDateFormatter` outputs a NSDate - which is always in GMT time.

If you want your initial string interpreted as GMT time then you need to include the timezone.

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss aa z"];
NSDate *date =  [df dateFromString:@"4:15:00 PM GMT"];
```

Comment: Can I do this without having to change to append GMT to the input string?

Comment: If you don't put GMT then it is going to use your locale's timezone

Comment: If its defaulting then why do I have the issue where the time changes from "4:15:00 PM" to "12:15:00 PM"

Comment: Those are the same raw NSDate. It *looks* like it is changing because '4:15:00 PM', unless otherwise stated, is assumed to be in your current locales timezone. Where as NSDate is always stored in GMT time, so it does a timezone conversion *to* GMT time when you use `dateFromString`.