# NSDateFormatter in 12-hour mode

Tags: objective-c, ios, datetime, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have the following code.

```
NSDateFormatter *df = ...;
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ"];
NSDate * date = [df dateFromString:date_string]; //here is the problem
```

In 24-hour mode everything is ok. When 12-hour mode is set on device, stringFromDate returns null.
Format of date_string is the same all the time, date format too. Why does it happen?

Comment: can u display the date_string value!

Comment: 2012-06-16T10:00:47.436+0000
for instance

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6613110/581994).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try to set the locale in this way :

```
NSLocale *twelveHourLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
df.locale = twelveHourLocale;
```

To force instead to 24 hour, you can use :

```
NSLocale *twentyFour = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"];
```

Comment: I would like to force dateformatter to ignore 12-hour mode and use 24-hour all the time. What loc identifier should I use?

Comment: en_GB --> NSLocale* formatterLocale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"] autorelease];

Comment: Brilliant! Works like a charm.

Comment: Do not recommend. "hh" means 12 hour, and "HH" means 24 hour

Answer (score 56):

In your `NSDateFormatter "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ"` `HH` stands for 24 hour and `hh` stands for 12 hour

Comment: I want to ignore 12-hour system settings and don't know how

Comment: @Sergey then use **hh** instead of **HH**

Comment: join this chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/12634/chat-nsdateformatter?tab=general

Comment: This is not true. If user has 24 hour turned off and uses HH, it will still be 12 hour format.

Comment: And if you like to add AM / PM, add letter "a" at the end of your format string like this: "hh:mm a"

Answer (score 6):

12-hour mode to 24 hour mode:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
NSDate *amPmDate = [formatter dateFromString:amPmHourString];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSString *24HourString = [formatter stringFromDate:amPmDate]];
```

For 24-hour mode to 12 hour mode just do the opposite

Answer (score 4):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] 
                initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] autorelease];  
[dateFormat setLocale:locale];
```