# NSDateFormatter dateFromString: returns nil on specific device

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdate

I have an app that parses a string date using NSDateFormatter in the following way:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

if( !date )
    NSLog(@"Cannot parse date: %@", dateString);
```

This works on all of our test devices but fails on one single client device. The value of dateString is `"25/04/2014 17:22"`

What could cause this to fail?

Comment: client timestamp is diffrent of your . i think that's problem .

Comment: code is correct but have you checked that your client get `dateString `

Comment: The dateString is the same on both, this has been confirmed by using a log file to output the failed parse.

Comment: No locale is set but we're not using EEE or anything locale specific. It just uses the date format as specified.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that this single device has 12-hour time format set? If so, this answer might be helpful: 
[NSDateFormatter in 12-hour mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062280/nsdateformatter-in-12-hour-mode)

Comment: Some POSIX locale might be useful then, which isn't affected by user settings.

Comment: I'm going to try setting the locale and see if this makes a difference. The time is set to 12-hour on the failing device but the date format should not be affected by this as we explicitly set the format without relying on the system locale. Also, it works perfectly on a simulator set to 12-hour too. Will give it a shot and accept this answer if it works.