# Am I using the correct format pattern for parsing a date?

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter, date-formatting

I have problem using the **NSDateFormatter** to parse a date string. I have implemented the method method below as an **NSDate** category. The input is the following date string *Thu, 22 Dec 2011 16:03:39 +0100* and using the following pattern for parsing *EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ*

The problem is that the method returns *nil*

```
+(NSDate*) dateFromString:(NSString*)dateString pattern:(NSString*)pattern
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateParser = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateParser setDateFormat:pattern];

    NSDate *parsedDate = [dateParser dateFromString:dateString];

return parsedDate;
}
```

I have looked on Stackoverflow and elsewhere on the Internet, but not found a solution to this problem.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You should set the locale of the date formatter to `[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]`

Comment: Yes, please specify what the problem is.  And note what Fabian says about using en_US_POSIX -- there's a "feature" of iOS that time formatting gets screwed up if the 12/24 switch in Settings is in contradiction to the locale.

Comment: I have clarified what the problem is. Tested the solution as presented by @FabianKreiser and it works. However I do not understand why this method works for some date parsing and do not work for other. I have used this code successfully. Can someone please explain why?

Comment: @HotLicks Is there a simple workaround for this 'feature'?

Comment: See my answer. I also try to explain why NSDateFormatter changes its behavior based on the locale.

Comment: @FabianKreiser have marked your answer as the preferred answer.

Comment: Yes.  As I indicated, you should do what Fabian suggested.  You can see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6735644/581994) for a category you can create to encapsulate setting the locale.  Also see that thread for several references explaining Apple's problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSDateFormatter` is quite smart about region settings like 12/24 hour display, month and weekday names, etc.
If you initialize a date formatter it always uses the current locale, you can set the locale manually, though. You can use the `en_US_POSIX` locale identifier to get a date formatter back that doesn't respect locale settings and always uses the same behavior.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
```

This is handy (and required, actually) if you need to parse date strings returned from a server for example.

If you want to display date strings in your app, you should never use the `-setDateFormat:` method directly, btw. Use `+dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale:` method to get the correct date format.

In some languages the month is written before the day, ...

```
    NSString *dateFormat = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"dd MMMM yyyy" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:dateFormat];
```