# NSDateFormat (Unicode) issues

Tags: objective-c, unicode, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I trying to convert a NSString that looks like this:

```
@"00:00 15 September 2012"
```

to a NSDate.

I can't figure out what the unicode format needs to be. I am trying this:

```
@"HH:mm dd MMMM YYYY"
@"HH:mmddMMMMYYYY"
```

I've been trying to follow the [rules here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) but to no avail.

---

**EDIT:**

Paul's answer does work (except for military time problem). I was trying to use Apple's example of how to create a format template like so:

```
NSString *formatString = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"hh:mm dd MMM yyyy" options:0
                                                              locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

NSDateFormatter* fmt = [NSDateFormatter new];
[fmt setDateFormat:formatString];
```

This causes everything to spit out null.

However, if I do this:

```
NSDateFormatter* fmt = [NSDateFormatter new];
[fmt setDateFormat:@"hh:mm dd MMM yyyy"];
```

All is well in the world. My only guess is that NSLocale doesn't work in simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wasn't far off, you need something like:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm dd MMM yyyy";
dateFormatter.timeZone = [[NSTimeZone alloc] initWithName:@"GMT"];

NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"00:00 15 September 2012"]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! That does work but is `00:00` correct for handling military time? Anytime that is `12:59+` spits out `null`.

Comment: Ah, go it. I updated my question if you could take a look at it again.

Comment: Yeah, "hh" is a 12-hour clock, while "HH" is a 24-hour clock.  [Except when the user sets the 12/24 switch in Settings "backwards"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformater-locale-feature).