# Objective c NSDate From current day and time from NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Pretty simple question, but I'm wondering how to make an NSDate from current date and time from NSString
NSString content format is like this:"hh:mm:ss"
Simple, but I can't do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`NSDateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/) class to do that.

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[df setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate* date = [df dateFromString:@"20:31:39"];
```

Comment: It should be noted, however, that a ["feature"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformater-locale-feature) of iOS can "bite" you and cause problems if the phone is set up certain ways.