# Convert Date into String without Using NSDateFormatter

Tags: objective-c, iphone, nsstring, nsdate

How to convert `NSDate` into `NSString` without use of `NSDateFormatter`?

For Your reference my code as follows , i am using it for my reminder application.

Thank You So Much.

```
 NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

// Get the current date
NSDate *pickerDate = [self->dp date];



// Break the date up into components
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit )
                                               fromDate:pickerDate];
NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit )
                                               fromDate:pickerDate];

// Set up the fire time
NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComps setDay:[dateComponents day]];
[dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
[dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];
[dateComps setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
// Notification will fire in one minute
[dateComps setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];
[dateComps setSecond:[timeComponents second]];
NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
[dateComps release];
```

Comment: Then why don't you store those dates in the NSDate type... you don't need to use any of the formatter ;)

Comment: very simple process is typecast the date into nsstring or use stringWithFormat . I think you go your answer.

Comment: Because i want to store that date as an string in database.

Comment: What's your problem with NSDateFormatter???  Much cleaner and more efficient than using NSCalendar for converting to string.

Comment: @Anand -- You are so very wrong -- see below.

Comment: Re your code above: You realize, of course, that if you simply want a date some time in the future, you can use `[pickerDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:numberOfseconds]`.  No need to break things down with NSCalendar and reassemble them.

Comment: I was the first who gave you right answer but you didn't consider it, and it was right and same of what you choose.

Comment: @RandeepSingh -- Yeah, I gave you +1 for having the only (almost) totally right answer in the bunch.

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks for that i know u did, but this was for the questionner actually i was expecting to get my answer accepted.

Comment: @RandeepSingh - Well, things don't always work out the way you'd like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your question you can get it in this way -

```
NSString *stringDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",pickerDate];
NSLog(@"%@",stringDate);

NSString *stringDate = [pickerDate description];
NSLog(@"%@", stringDate);
```

You can also get `NSString` by using `NSDateFormatter` why're you getting fear to use it ?

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

NSString *stringDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:pickerDate];  
NSLog(@"%@", stringDate);
```

Comment: `NSDateFormatter` will set the format what kind of date you want ... but as he asked this code is okay. He dont want the format he is asking for `NSDate` to `NSString` ...

Comment: NSDateFormatter `stringFromDate` will convert NSDate to NSString.

Comment: Every one know that but look at the question he asking without `NSDateFormatter` and i this is converting what is the issue .. ???

Comment: Converting with `description` is not supported for "live" code -- it's only for test/diagnostics.

Comment: This is @Mahesh Dhapa's problem i just gave the answer according to question... :) In my code i would never do that without `NSDateFormatter` ... According to question this is okay.

Comment: `NSString *stringDate = (NSString *)pickerDate;` does not convert the `pickerDate` in any way.

Comment: @MartinR -- Yep, all casting does is hide an NSDate in a variable labeled NSString.  When you later use the variable in a `%@` format, `description` will be invoked, so it *seems* like casting was effective, but it does nothing.

Comment: Note that `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",pickerDate]` does a `[pickerDate description]` under the covers.

Comment: @VakulSaini - Yes, the formatter is the best way.  `description` *should not* be used in "real" code, only diagnostics.

Comment: Good!! ... Thanks for sharing the knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

Folks, read the [documentation for NSDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html), fer cryin' out loud!!!

> description
>
> Returns a string representation of the receiver.
>
> `- (NSString *)description`
>
> Return Value
>
> A string representation of the receiver.
>
> Discussion
>
> **The representation is not guaranteed to remain constant across
>   different releases of the operating system. To format a date, you
>   should use a date formatter object instead (see NSDateFormatter and
>   Data Formatting Guide)**

It should also be understood that when you do `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", something]`, what occurs is that the code behind `%@` formatting invokes the `description` method of `something`.  For NSString objects the `description` method is defined to reliably return the string value, but for all other Cocoa classes `description` is intended for diagnostic use only.

The other alternative to NSDateFormatter (besides the backwards NSCalendar scheme) is to crack the date yourself -- not that difficult, really, and at least an interesting exercise.

[If you want to try cracking the date yourself, use `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`, which returns an NSTimeInterval object (really just a typecast `double`) that represents seconds since Jan 1 2001 (negative for dates before then).  The value will be UTC, so add/subtract any timezone offset if you want local time, then start using modulo arithmetic.  You can easily get it to milliseconds, seconds, minutes, and hours, plus a "days since Jan 1 2001" value.  From there converting to day/month/year requires thought, but is not terribly difficult, especially if you confine yourself to dates after 1900.]

Answer (score 1):

I am using this and saving in to database as **string** only.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"];

NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];  
NSLog(@"Current time date:%@", dateString);
```

Comment: The only "gotcha" is that [you should set the date formatter's locale to "en_US".](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformater-locale-feature)

Answer (score 0):

According to your question you can get it in this way -

```
NSString *stringDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",pickerDate];
NSLog(@"%@",stringDate);

NSString *stringDate = [pickerDate description];
NSLog(@"%@", stringDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"Current time date:%@", dateString);
```

Comment: Please edit your question for providing some style according SOF structure. Some context for the answer will be appreciated as well.

Comment: Note that the OP specified *without use of `NSDateFormatter`*.