# NSDate format correct on Simulator, incorrect on device

Tags: ios, ios6, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm using `NSDateFormatter` to format dates to relative dates. In Simulator, the dates appear correctly as "November 12, 2012", however on my device the same date appears as "2012-11-12". I'm running the same OS version both.

Here's the code I am using:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormatter setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:YES];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateToDisplay];
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yep, set the locale if you're not explicitly setting the date format.  And even (especially) if you do explicitly set the format you need to beware of the [12/24 hour "feature"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformatter-locale-feature).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably different localization. Check Settings --> General --> International on both your device and simulator. You can set the locale of your `dateFormatter` like

```
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en/US"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:locale];
```

Comment: OK, thanks, that seems to be the issue alright. However, if I force `en/US` wouldn't that return the correct translation for dates? If the OS language is set to French, I'd prefer not display the English month or way of displaying the dates.. Any idea?

Comment: @runmad Do not set the locale on the date formatter unless you have a specific reason to format the date in that locale. By default, a date formatter uses the current locale based on the Region Format setting in the Settings app.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the clarification. Odd that Canadian English default to "yyyy-MM-dd" instead of relative dates.