# Reliably testing NSDateFormatter/iOS's 12-hour format-rewriting behavior

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsdateformatter, time-format

[On iOS, NSDateFormatter has a “feature” where it rewrites your format string if the user has 12-hour time enabled.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformatter-locale-feature)

I can fix that easily enough (set the formatter's locale to `en_US_POSIX`); that's not the difficulty.

My difficulty is that I want to create a test case that detects the 12-hour-rewriting behavior. I want to set things up so that when my formatter (which should only ever emit 24-hour date strings) spits out a 12-hour date string, at least one test case fails.

I have an iOS test bundle set for SDK current (currently 6.1), target 5.0. When I run my tests under this target, all of my times are still 24-hour.

[I have at least one report of this occurring in the wild](https://github.com/boredzo/iso-8601-date-formatter/issues/15), so all I need now is to reproduce it reliably in a test case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to check:

```
NSString *newFmt = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"HH" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
if ([newFmt hasPrefix:@"h"]) {
    // User in 24-hour locale has iOS device set to 12-hour time
}
```

This can be tested by running the Settings app and going to General, then International. Set the Region Format to the United Kingdom. Then go to General, Date & Time, and set the time format to 12-hour. Then run this code.

Comment: There is on all of my iOS devices running iOS 5 and up. You need to scroll down a bit on the General page.

Comment: You can't test this in the simulator.

Comment: It's increasingly looking that way, in the sense that iOS in the Simulator seemingly does not have this “feature”. The Settings app and status bar show a 12-hour time in my locale (US), but `dateFormatFromTemplate:::` returns “HH”. So, it may just be only on real devices. Yaaay.

Comment: Yep, another reason why apps must be tested on real devices and not just the simulator. :)

Comment: The "feature" only goes one way - in locale's with 12-hour time as the norm, the format works unaltered regardless of the 24-hour time setting. But in locale's with 24-hour time as the norm, the format gets changed if the user changes the 24-hour time setting to 12-hour. Since the simulator lacks the 24-hour setting, this must be tested on real devices using locales that use 24-hour time as the norm.

Comment: I wonder whether there's a user default or combination of defaults I could set/register to fake NSDF into thinking that the 12-hour preference is set.