# Not getting date whien time format in 24 hours iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am converting the string into date with the help of below code :

> ```
> NSDateFormatter *fDateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];  
> [fDateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a"];  
> [fDateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];  
> NSDate *dateFormat = [fDateFormat dateFromString:strDate];
> ```

And passing string like **"02/09/2013 05:10 AM"** and I will get date perfect. But when we use **time format 24 hours, then date is nil.**

Can you please me out of this problem ?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6735644/581994).  Playing with the phone's 12/24 setting mucks up NSDateFormatter unless you take special precautions.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDateFormatter *fDateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];  
[fDateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a"];  
[fDateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];  
NSDate *dateFormat = [fDateFormat dateFromString:strDate];  

[fDateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"];  
NSString *your24Format = [fDateFormat stringFromDate:dateFormat];
```

You can try above code, should be working fine :)

Wayne