# Hardware-dependent NSDateFormatter dateFromString: bug (returns nil)

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, iphone-5

I have several date strings that I need to convert to NSDates.
My parsing code is the following:

```
NSString *s = [pair objectForKey:@"nodeContent"];
NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[f setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ"];
self.date = [f dateFromString:s];
```

The above code works fine in all the devices and simulators we've tested.
The strange thing is that when the above code runs on any iPhone 5 running iOS 6.1 or 7.0.x , the line `self.date = [f dateFromString:s];` returns nil every time.

I have checked and the string `s` exists and contains the same characters when compared side-by-side with a device that does parse the date correctly.

This is an example date string:
`2013-10-31T21:50:00-06:00'

Am I missing something here?

Comment: quantify *any*. Could it be an issue with the locale?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to deal with the NSDateFormatter locale "feature"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformatter-locale-feature)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's because you are not setting the date formatter's locale to the special `en_US_POSIX` locale. Most likely your iPhone 5 has a different setting for the 24-hour setting.

You need to set the special locale whenever you parse a fixed format string.

Comment: Thank you. I added the line `[f setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];` and it works now.