# DateFormatter sets AM/PM by default

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to convert the current time and date to a timestamp format. Since the service is receiving this format for timestamps:

```
2018-26-11T11:38:00Z
```

I decided to use a format like this:

```
yyyy-M-dd'T'H:mm:ss'Z'
```

But, when I use a date formatter to convert it, I'm getting an unwanted AM/PM tag at the end by default:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-M-dd'T'H:mm:ss'Z'"
let currentTimeAndDate = Date()
let timeStamp = dateFormatter.string(from: currentTimeAndDate)
// Prints "2018-12-05T12:58:38 PMZ"
```

How can I remove that AM/PM by default at the end of the string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hardware-dependent NSDateFormatter dateFromString: bug (returns nil)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578433/hardware-dependent-nsdateformatter-datefromstring-bug-returns-nil)

Answer (score 2):

- Set the locale to fixed `en_US_POSIX"`

  ```
  dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
  ```
- Or use the dedicated ISO8601 formatter

  ```
  let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
  let currentTimeAndDate = Date()
  let timeStamp = dateFormatter.string(from: currentTimeAndDate)
  ```

Answer (score -1):

1. Use `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX` for the format.
2. Set the formatter's `timeZone` to `TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)`.
3. Set the locale to the special "en_US_POSIX" locale: `Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")`

Updated code:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
let currentTimeAndDate = Date()
let timeStamp = dateFormatter.string(from: currentTimeAndDate)
```

Or avoid all of that and use `ISO8601DateFormatter`.