# Is it possible to change the iOS Simulator to use 24 hour time?

Tags: ios, time, ios-simulator, date-formatting, time-format

I'm trying to debug a potential issue in the iOS Simulator (v 7.0) which requires the iPad to be running in 24-hour time mode. Obviously, the option is not available to change in the simulator itself and changing the time mode on my host system didn't do the trick either.

Any advice on making this change?  Is it even possible? Seems like a pretty basic thing but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

Comment: Test on a real iOS device.

Comment: Tried that but my iPad has been upgraded to iOS7 whereas the user reporting the issue is still on 6.1.  Trying to isolate the issue by running on as similar an environment as possible.

Comment: If the issue is about parsing a date then testing on iOS 7 should be the same.

Comment: Re the 12/24 bug problem, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6735644/581994).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you switch the region format to a country that uses 24-hour time as a standard (e.g. France) inside the simulator then it should work for you.

Go to Simulator / Settings App / General / Language & Region / Region / Select the Region

You can use France for 24-hour time, or Hong Kong for 12-hour time.

Comment: Thanks.  Worked like a charm.  I still wish they made this easier but at least this is an easy work around.

Comment: What if you want to set to 12 hour time zone in a foreign country (other than if U.S, like France)

Comment: in Xcode 6.x. Simulator / Settings / General / Language & Region / Region / Select France or  other countries.(simulator will automatically use 24 hour time)

Comment: If you set the Region to Hong Kong, it'll use 12-hour time (e.g. 3:34 PM)

Answer (score 4):

Time zone can be changed by system only System Preference/Date & Time select time zone and change.After changing time zone by system it will reflect in your simulator. iPhone simulator has no option to change time zone.

Comment: Question is not asking about time zone. Also, changing the relevant 24 hour setting in System Preferences for your Mac (which are located in Language  & Region) does not seem to affect the 12 / 24 hour formatting of the simulator.

Comment: I'd have to call this a simulator bug, we have study participants who have military backgrounds and some prefer to have their phones in 24-hr time, so thinking that 24-hr time is solely a locale thing is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

First change the MAC Time settings to your required format and time zone by Launchpad/SystemPreferences/Date and Time. Then restart your simulator.

For reflecting the 24 hour format you need to change the simulator settings app also

Simulator/Settings/General/Language & Region/Change the region to match your mac settings.

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: Correct its not working