# NSDateFormatter can't format with "yyyy-MM-dd a hh:mm" in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

**in cocoa**:

NSDateFormatter can't format with  `"yyyy-MM-dd a hh:mm",` 
it return `2013-12-05 10:48`, lose 'AM' part.
but it work with "`yyyy-MM-dd"` a " or "`yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm`"

**in ios**:

`"yyyy-MM-dd a hh:mm"` can work, it return `2013-12-05 AM 10:48`

Comment: Set your locale to a "safe" one.

Comment: See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformatter-locale-feature