# Wrong Conversion

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

NSDateFormatter converting into wrong date don't know why

I am converting following string **19-01-2014 01:06:54 PM** into date using following code

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:startTime];
```

And i am getting following output which is incorrect.Please suggest some thing

**Printing description of date:
2014-01-04 07:36:54 +0000**

Answer (score 1):

The "DD-MM-YYYY" part in your format string is not correct, is should be "dd-MM-yyyy".
(See http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns for a
full list of all date formats.)

Also you should set a "POSIX locale" to be independent of the user's locale/region
settings:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
[dateFormat setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:startTime];
```

Comment: You can also set a timezone and calendar *instead* of a locale, if that makes more sense.

Comment: @trojanfoe: That are two different things. Setting the POSIX locale is useful if the input has a fixed *format*, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformatter-locale-feature. - Setting the timezone can be done if the date itself should not be interpreted in the local timezone. I don't know if that is also an issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Printing an NSDate will return the default description -- since NSDates don't take locale, timezone, etc. into consideration, it defaults to UTC +/- 0000 (notice the +0000).

Comment: but still there is much gap between date 4 and 19 ??

Comment: That's because your date format string is incorrect (see martin's answer)

Comment: By the way, in regards to my answer -- a nice little helper method I like to use for debugging is `-[NSDate descriptionWithLocale:]`