# Can't parse date from string

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I can't parse date from string via NSDateFormatter. The date string is `@"2014-01-21T20:00:36+04:00"`. I am trying to use this format string: `@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"` but it doesn't work. Please help me.

The full code is:

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ";
NSDate * date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Comment: See [here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for date format patterns.  And also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformatter-locale-feature) for info on something that will bite you if you don't watch out.

Comment: And most people put the T in single quotes, though I'm not sure it's necessary.

Comment: BTW, this is probably about #3 on the most asked questions list, so be nice or we'll vote you down and close the question as a dupe.

Comment: @HotLicks sorry i was really confused by this problem and didn't know how to solve :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add Z at the end `@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"` as you have timezone included

Comment: Use ZZZZZ for the timezone -- it's a sleepy one.

Comment: @AlexanderPerechnev - I beg to differ.

Comment: try to put T in ' so make it @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ" and only 3 times Z

Answer (score 0):

Following on from http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns

```
NSString *dateString = @"2014-01-21T20:00:36+04:00";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

dateFormat.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ";
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];

NSLog(@"Parsed date is %@", date);
```

yields the following output which seems correct

```
Parsed date is 2014-01-21 16:00:36 +0000
```