# NSDate returning nil for the NSDateFormatter set correctly

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am getting the date in NSString format as mentioned below.

**Input:datestring =  30/04/2013 04:49 PM**

I am applying the format for NSDateformatter as mentioned below to convert this NSString to NSDate .

**Format:dateFormat= dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a**

I still get the date conversion to Nil. Please help as I am not understanding this issue.Here is my code snippet to explain what i am doing in the utility function.

```
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:dateFormat];
  NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
  return date;
```

Comment: Use the same date formatter to format (ie, stringFromDate) `[NSDate date]` and print the result.  Does it come out exactly as your format shows?

Comment: (You may be getting bit by the date formatter [locale "feature"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformatter-locale-feature).)

Answer (score 0):

Try This....

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"30/04/2013 04:49 PM"];
NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

Comment: Why would setting timezone affect whether or not the result is nil?

Comment: No, because of UTC timezone is the time standard commonly used across the world.

Comment: But he's not getting an incorrect result, he's getting a nil result.  How would setting timezone (which would otherwise default to local TZ) prevent a nil result?

Comment: Which is not true for the OP.