# IOS - Date string with NSDateFormatter doesn't recognize HH format

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have this date string:

```
NSString *dateString = @"2014-05-08T16:48:45.000Z";
```

and I want convert this one to NSDate.

So, I did this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

=> return: (null)

To understand what create this problem I tried element by element like this:

```
NSString *dateString = @"2014-05-08T";
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'"]
```

=> return 2014-05-08 07:00:00 AM +0000 (good!)

But when I had "HH":

```
 NSString *dateString = @"2014-05-08T16";
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH"]
```

=> return: (null)

WTF???

Comment: Set the formatter's locale to the special locale of `en_US_POSIX`. It solves this sort of problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to deal with the NSDateFormatter locale "feature"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformatter-locale-feature)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rmaddy give us the solution:

Set the formatter's locale to the special locale of `en_US_POSIX`