# Objective-C - Date format not recognized by device

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have one date on `NSString` with format: `"Jun 25, 2014 10:10:15 AM"`

I need to put this date from one `NSDate`. But I tried some formats on date format and always value of `NSDate` is nil on device. If I run by Xcode on device or on simulator its work but i generate a .ipa and send to iPhone not work.

code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];
NSDate * dataStringFormatted = [dateFormat dateFromString: @"Jun 25, 2014 10:10:15 AM"];
```

I tried formats:

```
@"MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a"
@"MMM dd, yyyy H:mm:ss a"
@"MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss aa"
@"MMM dd, yyyy H:mm:ss aa"
@"MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss aaa"
@"MMM dd, yyyy H:mm:ss aaa"
@"MMMM dd, yyyy H:mm:ss aa"
@"MMMM dd, yyyy H:mm:ss aaa"
@"MMMM dd, yyyy H:mm:ss a"
@"MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss A"
```

With all formats always the Object `NSDate` is nil.

Thank.

Comment: It should be noted that NSDateFormatter is a little fussy about reading date strings containing the day of the week.  Sometimes it's best to simply strip off day-of-week before parsing.

Comment: probably you are not using english localisation on your device.

Comment: Yes, I not used the localization and the "hh" to hours PM/AM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There a two issues with your code, `HH` is for 24 hour dates and you should tell the formatter which language the date is going to be in:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
NSDate * dataStringFormatted = [dateFormat dateFromString: @"Jun 25, 2014 10:10:15 AM"];
```

Comment: Also, one needs to be aware of the date formatter locale "feature": http://stackoverflow.com/q/6613110/581994

Comment: @HotLicks That is in the answer, as long as the date he want to parse are in english setting the local `en_US_POSIX` should do the trick.

Comment: Really its works.
Laked attetion by the HH and i didn't know locale are needed
Thank you