# Xcode Date Formatting - Format from RSS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdateformatter

I always have trouble with this, and keep seem to find a good resource to learn this exhaustively.  I am trying to use the date formatter in Xcode objective C, but I am not setting the date format correctly.  Here is my data:

```
Fri, 27 Jun 2014 12:33:18 +0000
```

Can someone assist me or point me in the right direction? Trying the below code, but it is not working.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d LLL yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
```

Update: the format below might help, as it shows some zero padding on the day.

```
Wed, 02 Jul 2014 11:47:35 +0000
```

Comment: Your format is wrong, but two other points:  1) the [locale "feature"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6613110/581994) can bite you, and 2) the date formatter is a little fussy about reading dates with the day-of-week included, and you're often better off substringing the date to remove day-of-week.

Comment: Thanks for the note.  Is there a way to calm the fussiness?  If not, i like your idea of trimming the day-of-week off.

Comment: Simply substring to the comma, to remove the day of week.  But fixing the locale problem and setting some of the NSDateFormatter default settings may help -- I've never been in a situation where I needed to track down the culprit that badly.

Comment: Makes sense I'll go that route for sure.  Just want to understand fully, which is why I'm pushing for a solid answer. Are you suggesting that I remove the setLocale line of code as well?

Comment: It's best to use the "en_US_POSIX" locale, since otherwise you can get bit by the "locale feature".  Some have mumbled that playing with, I think, the "style" settings can have some effect on the day-of-week parsing issue, but I've never seen it nailed down reliably, since the whole issue is intermittent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Unicode Technical Standard #35](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns), "LLL" is the date format for a "stand-alone month" which is "a month name without an associated day number". 
You should use "MMM" instead:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
```

Example:

```
NSString *str = @"Fri, 27 Jun 2014 12:33:18 +0000";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:str];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
// Output: 2014-06-27 12:33:18 +0000
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working. I am still getting a null date field when I create a date from the dateFormatter object. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I discovered that the format might not be slightly clear from my original post.  I will update it accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, bookmark the date formatter spec link above, as you'll probably need to refer to it frequently.

Comment: @nlabhart: Do you convert a NSDate to a NSString or NSString to NSDate? Is "Wed, 02 Jul 2014 11:47:35 +0000" is *input* or the *output*?

Comment: @MartinR I am converting NSString to NSDate.  The format "Wed, 02 Jul 2014 11:47:35 +0000" is the NSString.

Comment: @nlabhart: Converting the string "Wed, 02 Jul 2014 11:47:35 +0000" to NSDate worked without problems in my test program, with the date format "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z" suggested in my answer. (Actually it worked with your date format "EEE, d LLL yyyy HH:mm:ss Z" as well.) - What result do you get?

Comment: Strange - I am still getting nil with both formats.  Can you post the code you are using, if you don't mind?

Comment: @nlabhartL: Any progress?