# How to reuse a NSString method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, locale, nsdateformatter

I am writing a method that takes string and returns string. I am trying to use it in another method.

```
- (NSString*) formatDate:(NSString*) showStartDateTime
{
    NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:tz];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MM/dd/yyyy"];
    NSDate*dattt=[dateFormatter dateFromString:showStartDateTime ];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSString*tempo2= [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dattt];
    return tempo2;

}
```

This is how I am using it. [self formatDate:@"Fri 08/08/2014"] is it a correct way to use it?

```
NSString *hellostring=[self formatDate:@"Fri 08/08/2014"];
NSLog(@"%@",hellostring);
```

I know it does not work. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: I just ran it, and my console output is "2014-08-08" as expected.

Comment: @danh I am trying to see if I can reuse this method to simply pass a string and get back to correct format.

Comment: @Neprocker please define "correct format".  Maybe you should edit the question to say exactly what you hope the method will do.

Comment: @danh The method pretty obviously is attempting to convert a NSString date from "EEE MM/dd/yyyy" to "yyyy-MM-dd" format.  And it's getting bit by some flakiness in the date formatter in that if you try to parse a day-of-week value it often fails.  As vikingosegundo indicates, this problem appears to be somehow interconnected with the [locale "feature"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6613110/581994), but I prefer to deal with it by removing the day-of-week info before attempting to parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a command line app and wasnt able to get it running, as already `dateFromString:` resulted in nil, until I added  `dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];`

```
- (NSString*) formatDate:(NSString*) showStartDateTime
{
    NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:tz];

    dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MM/dd/yyyy"];
    NSDate*dattt=[dateFormatter dateFromString:showStartDateTime ];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSString*tempo2= [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dattt];
    return tempo2;

}
```

Now it returns `2014-08-08`

see [Technical Q&A QA1480: NSDateFormatter and Internet Dates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html)