# swift NSDateFormatter not working

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to format time as follows:

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "hh_mm_ss"
let d = formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
println("formatted text is: \(d)")
```

Suppose that current time is Sep 3, 2014 22:15:30

1. When I run this script on playground, it prints the time correctly formatted: `22_15_30`.
2. When running this on AppDelegate, it doesn't print the time formatted: `22:15:30`

I'm using xcode 6 beta 5... Am I missing something? Why stringFromDate doesn't return the correct date formatted?

**EDIT**: I'm using xcode 6 beta 6.

Thanks!

Comment: Works great for me: `formatted text is: 12_11_33` - maybe upgrade to beta 7?

Comment: Works as expected for me.

Comment: The 24-hour format is "HH", not "hh".

Comment: Thanks @MartinR, I changed the format to "HH" and now it prints what I was expecting. The weird thing is that "hh" works on playground :S Please, can you answer the question so I can mark as OK?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 24-hour format is "HH", not "hh".

The reason that it works in the Playground *may be*
that user defined settings can override the 12/24-format choice, compare
[What is the best way to deal with the NSDateFormatter locale "feechur"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformatter-locale-feature). 
To be on the safe side, set the "en_US_POSIX" locale for the date formatter:

```
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")

// Swift 3:
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```