# NSDateFormatter fails on iOS 7, works on later versions

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to parse a String in the format "ddMMyy-HH:mm:ss" using the following code

```
static func parseDate(var date: String?) -> NSDate?{
        if(date == nil){
            return nil
        }
        print("PARSING \(date)")
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "ddMMyy-HH:mm:ss"
        let res = formatter.dateFromString(date!)
        print("RESULT \(res)")
        return res
    }
```

The value of res is nil at the end, even though date is not nil. I then tried removing the : and - symbols using

```
  date = date!.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(":", withString: "")
  date = date!.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("-", withString: "")
```

And then changing my format to reflect this

```
formatter.dateFormat = "ddMMyyHHmmss"
```

The console output now is

```
TIME IS 291015-12:10:12
PARSING Optional("291015121012")
RESULT nil
```

I also tried adding the line

```
formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
```

The strange thing is, the app works perfectly on iOS 9 and I think it worked on 8 too.

Comment: I tried your code with format `ddMMyy-HH:mm:ss` and `121212-12:12:12` and the result is `"Dec 12, 2012, 12:12 PM"` which is correct

Comment: @WilliamKinaan on iOS7?

Comment: Oh i see now, no sorry it is iOS 9

Comment: Set the locale to "en_US_POSIX", compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25657123/swift-nsdateformatter-not-working or other answers containing "en_US_POSIX locale".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was nothing to do with iOS, it was to do with the fact that my ios7 device happened to be in 12 hour mode in device settings. This confused the formatter. Using

```
    formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

as suggested by @WiliamKinaan fixed this