# Swift 3 Calendar adding Minutes does not change day

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsdate, nsdateformatter

In Swift 3 I am not able to change the day by adding minutes to a day. The time changes like its supposed to but the day does not change, for example adding 180 minutes to 31.10.2016 2200 leads to 31.10.2016 0100 and not to 01.11.2016 0100.

```
func getDayByAddingMinutes(date: String, minutes: Int) -> String{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm"
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let akt = (dateFormatter.date(from: date)! as Date?)!
    let calculatedDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .minute, value: minutes, to: akt )
    print("\(akt) +  \(minutes)")
    let dateFormatter2 = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter2.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
    let newDate = dateFormatter2.string(from: calculatedDate!);
    print("\(date) +  \(newDate)")
    return "\(newDate)";
}
```

Comment: The 24-hour date format is "HH", not "hh".

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25671175/1187415 (HH format and Posix locale).

Comment: dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") does not solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let minutes = 1000
let calendar = Calendar.current
let day = "23.01.2017"
let time = "21:15"
let inFormatter = DateFormatter()
inFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
inFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"
let d2 = inFormatter.date(from: "\(day) \(time)")!
let calculated = calendar.date(byAdding: .minute, value: minutes, to: d2)
let outFormatter = DateFormatter()
outFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
outFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
var date = outFormatter.string(from: calculated!)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
func getDayByAddingMinutes(date: String, minutes: Int) -> String{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm" 
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let akt = (dateFormatter.date(from: date)! as Date?)!
    let calculatedDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .minute, value: minutes, to: akt )
    print("\(akt) +  \(minutes)")
    let dateFormatter2 = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter2.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
    let newDate = dateFormatter.string(from: calculatedDate!);
    print("\(date) +  \(newDate)")
    return "\(newDate)";
}
```

You have used **hh** instead of **HH**.

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: unfortunately does not fix it :(

Comment: Do you have as a date string this format? **31.10.2016 2200** ?

If yes, you need to use **dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy HHmm"**

Comment: the parameter date looks like dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm
But the print statement in line 7 looks like that: 
2016-12-11 19:01:00 +0000 +  348
The time does not conform in this output, maybe because of the timezone, but the calculated HH:mm fits to the added minutes. 
Idk what +0000 means, maybe this is causing the issue?

Comment: +0000 means zulu time. That could be your issue. Unfortunately I am not sure how to overcome that hurdle. Afaik you need to set the locale to posix for both dareformatter.

Comment: Two questions:

1. What will be printed? **print( Date() )**
2. did you already tried this?  instead of calendar, use **let calculatedData = akt.addingTimeInterval( 60 * minutes)**