# Swift: One UITimePicker, Multiple Textfields

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I have a single `UIDatePicker` variable that has only the time. I want that to be able to set different times to different `TextFields`. The way I have it set up is that when I change one time, they all change.

Code:

```
*@IBOutlets for all the UITextFields...*

private var datePicker = UIDatePicker()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.setupDatePicker()
    self.setupTextFields()
}

func setupDatePicker() {
    self.datePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 200)
    self.datePicker.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
    self.datePicker.datePickerMode = .time
    self.datePicker.minuteInterval = 30
    self.datePicker.backgroundColor = .white
    self.datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.timeValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
}

func setupTextFields() {
    self.mondayOpenTF.inputView = self.datePicker
    self.mondayCloseTF.inputView = self.datePicker
    self.tuesdayOpenTF.inputView = self.datePicker
    self.tuesdayCloseTF.inputView = self.datePicker
    self.wednesdayOpenTF.inputView = self.datePicker
    self.wednesdayCloseTF.inputView = self.datePicker
    self.thursdayOpenTF.inputView = self.datePicker
    self.thursdayCloseTF.inputView = self.datePicker
    self.fridayOpenTF.inputView = self.datePicker
    self.fridayCloseTF.inputView = self.datePicker
    self.saturdayOpenTF.inputView = self.datePicker
    self.saturdayCloseTF.inputView = self.datePicker
    self.sundayOpenTF.inputView = self.datePicker
    self.sundayCloseTF.inputView = self.datePicker
}

@objc
func timeValueChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
    let date: String = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)

    self.mondayOpenTF.text = date as String
    self.mondayCloseTF.text = date as String
    self.tuesdayOpenTF.text = date as String
    self.tuesdayCloseTF.text = date as String
    self.wednesdayOpenTF.text = date as String
    self.wednesdayCloseTF.text = date as String
    self.thursdayOpenTF.text = date as String
    self.thursdayCloseTF.text = date as String
    self.fridayOpenTF.text = date as String
    self.fridayCloseTF.text = date as String
    self.saturdayOpenTF.text = date as String
    self.saturdayCloseTF.text = date as String
    self.sundayOpenTF.text = date as String
    self.sundayCloseTF.text = date as String
}
```

Is it possible to have one `UIDatePicker` to manage all the times seperately, or do I have to create 14 different ones to fill for each textfield?

Answer (score 2):

So If you only want to populate the **currently selected** textfield with the date provided, AND all of your textfields are located within your ViewController's **MAIN** view (or which ever view you specify, you just have to make sure that the view whose subviews you're looping throw contains your `UITextField`s), you could just check for whichever textfield is the first responder, and then add data to it, like this:

```
@objc
func timeValueChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
    let date: String = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)

    if let textfield = view.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UITextField }) as? UITextView, textfield.isFirstResponder {
        textfield.text = date
    }
}
```

Also, you could potentially clean up your setup code with a similar method, like so:

```
setupTextFields() {

    for textfield in (view.subviews.map {$0 as? UITextField}.flatMap{$0}) {
        textfield.inputView = datePicker
    }
}
```

Comment: You should set date formatter locale to "en_US_POSIX". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25657123/swift-nsdateformatter-not-working/25671175#25671175 . Btw Swift is a type inferred language and casting a String as String is pointless

Comment: Good catch, I copied OP's code over, and forgot to clean that up!

Comment: I get the error `Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'text'`

Comment: Revised my answer, sorry!