# iOS 8.0.2 and NSDateFormatter format issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, nsdateformatter

Up until today and the release 8.0.2 I have been using,

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddhhmmss"];
NSString *keyDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

and have been getting the result: `20140926125522`.

But after the update I am now getting: `2014092612:55:22`.

I am then unable to convert the `keydate` to a `NSNumber` as it now contains `:`.

Is anyone else getting this?

** EDIT **

After reading the comments i decided to go into the device settings and in the time and settings section turned the Set Automatically to off and the issue went away. I then turned it back on and the issue did not reappear.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: If that's really the case, that's just plain wrong.  File a bug report.

Comment: (I'm thinking there should be a tag for iOS 8 bugs.)

Comment: Agree with @HotLicks

Comment: I'm running with an iPad 8.0.2 and I don't have such behavior.

Comment: Me too 4s 8.0.2 (12A405) , no such behaviour

Comment: I'm seeing it pretty consistently in my locale (en_IE), especially when I try rearranging the time elements (i.e. ssmmhh gets displayed as hh:mm:ss). The one thing that seems to work around the issue is the use of HH for hours i.e. use a 24 hour clock

Comment: This seems like it might be locale-related.  It may be too that it's somehow conflated with the [12/24 "feature"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformatter-locale-feature).

Comment: We need to get folks who can reproduce this to report the locale they're using and the setting of the 12/24 switch in the phone settings.

Comment: I set  locale of dateformatter  to @"en_IE" programatically , still works fine!!!

Comment: @Bhumit - Toggle your 12/24 switch.

Comment: Tried both modes multiple times still the same result @HotLicks

Comment: **Rick, one important note** is that date format is asking for 12-hour time.  So you will never see a time after 12 noon.  This may somehow relate to the bug as well.

Answer (score 0):

An immediate fix could be the following:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddhhmmss"]; 
NSString *keyDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
keyDate = [keyDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@""];
```

This is not a solution however and should be fixed by apple in upcoming release

**EDIT**

I just checked in iPhone 4s with 8.0.2 (12A405) and can't reproduce the problem , using XCode 6.1 beta 2. it produces desired output

```
Printing description of keyDate:
20140926061051
```

**EDIT 2**

Checked in two other devices , same result, so i can say it is not an apple bug

Comment: But this should not be necessary.  Apple should never have let such a glaring bug escape.  Their testing was clearly deficient.

Comment: Totally Agree with you i am also surprised by such a bug