# NSDateFormatter is not working with PET format

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want parse date strings from API with time zone PET. So I created NSDateFormatter and converting the string into date but unfortunately its not working. I am getting nil as the result. Any workarounds ?

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy zz"];
NSDate *newStartDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"Mon Sep 29 14:40:00 2014 PET"];

NSLog(@"newStartDate - %@",newStartDate);
```

Comment: NSTimeZone knownTimeZones returns the list of recognized timezones.  Odds are "PET" is not in the list.

Comment: But using [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation] will get a list, where PET is there. If we use [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames]; then "America/Lima" is PET

Comment: NSDateFormatter tends to be fussy about reading formats with "EEE" in them -- sometimes it works, sometimes not.  It's best to strip the day-of-week value from the string before parsing (and, of course, suitably modify the format string).  Also, be aware of the ["locale feature"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformatter-locale-feature).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the below function.It will Work...

```
     NSDate *newStartDate = [self dateFromString:@"Mon Sep 29 14:40:00 2014 PET"];

     NSLog(@"newStartDate - %@",newStartDate);


    - (NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString*)inDateString
    {
       NSDateFormatter  *pivotalDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
       NSDate * dateToBeReturned = nil;
       [pivotalDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH':'mm':'ss yyyy z"];

       NSString * timezoneAbbreviation = [[inDateString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]       lastObject];
       NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:timezoneAbbreviation];
      if (timeZone)
      {
        NSString *gmtTime = [inDateString    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:timezoneAbbreviation withString:@"GMT"];
        dateToBeReturned = [[pivotalDateFormatter dateFromString:gmtTime] dateByAddingTimeInterval:-timeZone.secondsFromGMT];
      }
    return dateToBeReturned;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];`

`NSDate *newStartDate = [NSDate date];`

`NSString *newStartDateStr = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:newStartDate];`

now change the dateformatter dateformat

`[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy zz"]; //set dateformat as per ur requirement`

`newStartDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:newStartDateStr];`

`NSLog(@"%@", newStartDate);`

u will get the dateformat u required

happy coding

Comment: Initially I dont have NSDate. so using NSDateFormatter only i can convert NSString into NSDate.

Comment: generally dateformatter has some default dateformat...so u first have to convert your date to string in that dateformat and then afterwards changing the dateformat u will get ur required dateformat

Comment: As I told Initially I dont have date, i have only string , so i need to convert that string into date??

Comment: take that string into a date variable without setting any dateformat to dateformatter, then transfer that date to another string. set ur required dateformat. and get ur required date from that string

Comment: If we do like that     NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSDate *dateTemp = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"Mon Sep 29 14:40:00 2014 PET"];
Now the dateTemp is nil.

Comment: because as i've said that ur dateformatter has some default dateformat.

Comment: I created a new dateformatter NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; without specifying any format. This is my string "Mon Sep 29 14:40:00 2014 PET"

Comment: @sreekanthk - You're making no sense.  When you supply an explicit date format it overrides any "default format".  And converting from NSDate to string and back to NSDate proves nothing.