# NSDate from String in Swift

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nscalendar

I've got a string (eg. "2014-11-06 16:32:01")
I want to turn this format into an NSDate object.
Here's what I'm doing:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
var date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2014-11-06 16:32:01")!
var myCalendar:NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)!
var myComponents = myCalendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.WeekdayOrdinalCalendarUnit, fromDate: date)
var year = myComponents.year
var month = myComponents.month
var day = myComponents.day
```

year, month, and day are each valued at 9223372036854775807. Am I getting the dateFormat wrong?

Comment: Just copypasted your example and got this: 2014-11-06 14:32:01 +0000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The date format is correct. But you have to specify all wanted units in the
`myCalendar.components(...)` call. All other components are set to `NSNotFound` aka `NSIntegerMax`,
which is `2^63 - 1 = 9223372036854775807` on the 64-bit architecture.

This should work:

```
var myComponents = myCalendar.components(.YearCalendarUnit | .MonthCalendarUnit | .DayCalendarUnit, fromDate: date)
```

Comment: This has given me the units:
year = 4;
month = -140590335715296;
day = -36028797018959872;

Comment: @DaveAlton: That is strange, I had tested the code before posting it. What does `println(date)` show? How did you print year/month/day?

Comment: For some reason println(date) isn't working. I'm getting the values by setting a breakpoint

Comment: Martin I just tested it. it showing correct date  let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        var date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2014-11-06 16:32:01")!
        var myCalendar:NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)!
        var myComponents = myCalendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.WeekdayOrdinalCalendarUnit, fromDate: date)
        
        println(date)
        var year = myComponents.year
        var month = myComponents.month
        var day = myComponents.day

Comment: @DaveAlton: Then you might be a "victim" of the "locale feature" (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformatter-locale-feature). Try adding `dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")` before the string-to-date conversion.

Comment: @DaveAlton: Does `dateFormatter.dateFromString("2014-11-06 16:32:01")` (without the `!`) return `nil`?

Comment: He needs only to deal with the 3 components he is trying to access. You can check how it can be done on my answer.

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus: Yes, and my suggested code shows how to fix OP's code to retrieve exactly the 3 components. I have tested that and it worked. – I really don't know why this answer deserves a downvote.

Comment: @DaveAlton: Any progress on this problem?

Comment: Hey, sorry. I gave up and worked on something else for a bit. Then my hard drive crashed a few weeks later. New hard drive and everything works fine now. Odd, eh?

Answer (score 1):

```
static func convertStringToNSDate(dateStr: String) -> NSDate
{
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat =  "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss '+0000'"
    let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateStr)

    return date!
}
```

On my code I am using that method in order to convert a string to NSDate. The only thing that you need to do is to change the dateFormat attribute to be the same as the date's format you want to convert.