# NSDateFormatter returns date object from invalid input

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsdateformatter

I got a NSDateFormatter initiliased the following way:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
```

In my Unit tests I do now check, whether the formatter behaves the correct way for certain invalid input data that does not match "*HH:mm:ss*". E.g:

```
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"10-31-01"]; // obviously not a time format in HH:mm:ss
```

I would expect the resulting NSDate to be nil, as the string should not match the dateFormatter's pattern.

In fact, the result is:

```
Printing description of date:
2000-01-01 09:31:01 +0000
```

1 hour offset due to the timezone, I guess. But still I don't want the formatter to return a result for an invalid input and would expect "nil":

```
XCTAssertNil(date);
```

Same (unexpected) result for the following formats:

```
@"23-59-59" // (see format above)
@"23-59:59"
@"23:59-59"
```

The formatter seems to interpret the dash as a colon and is thus able to interpret the string.

Same problem in Swift (see image from short playground implementation).

[image: enter code here]

Anybody got an idea, whether I am missing an explicit setting or whether this is expected and especially appreciated behavior?

---

**UPDATED with Bug Report from Apple**

> Please know that our engineering team has determined that this issue
>   behaves as intended based on the information provided.
>
> It appears that ICU’s udat_parseCalendar() is very lenient and still
>   is able to parse even if the string doesn’t exactly match the format. 
>   We understand preferring that the formatter return nil in these cases
>   but (1) there’s no easy way for us to know that the input string
>   doesn’t match the format since ICU allows it and doesn’t throw an
>   error and (2) suddenly returning nil in these cases would almost
>   certainly be a bincompat issue.

--> Will not be fixed, as it does NOT throw an error (it is rather error tolerant) and a change could break working code now.

Comment: Why 10-31-01 is invalid ?

Comment: Its not in the expected format with colons instead of dashes: "10:31:01" vs. "10-31-01" - whereas I would expect the last date to be Date-Month-Mear. I would expect "10:31:01" to be Hours:Mins:Seconds.

Comment: Here problem with time format. Please use this HH from 0 to 23 and hh from 1 to 12 (AM/PM)

Comment: @Sivajee, I am afraid I have to disagree, see the other example with "23:59:59" <-- I do want to have "HH" instead of "hh"

Comment: @Martin R: Thank you for the work around approach. As the post is now 2 years old. And I did not explicitly ask for a workaround: Is there (despite from the lenient attribute) a reason for this behavior or is it still open as bug. Then I would file a bug report.

Comment: @Lepidopteron: The *answer* is that the date formatter is extremely lenient when parsing, and apparently that did not change in the last 2 years. If you consider that a bug then you should file a report.

Comment: Already did so, thank you.

Comment: Question is updated with response from the Bugreport, filed at Apple. Will also answer the original question with the above statement from Apple.