# How to convert string to date correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, datetime, date-parsing, dateformatter

Why does dateFormatter return the correct date from an invalid format string?

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2020/////07////////10") //"Jul 10, 2020 at 12:00 AM"
```

Comment: May be this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26840499/nsdateformatter-still-parsing-instead-having-incorrect-format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will say more - it also works unexpectedly

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let dotDate = dateFormatter.date(from: "2020....07...10") // Optional(2020-07-09 21:00:00 +0000)
let commaDate = dateFormatter.date(from: "2020,,,,07,,,,10") // Optional(2020-07-09 21:00:00 +0000)
```

My version is probably the issue in internal implementation on Apple side and comparison with the ASCII code table, where the codes of these characters (`,`,`-`,`.`,`/`) are in order (from 44 to 47)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a part of their algorithm.

If you want the formatter to return `nil` in this case you can change the dateFormat to:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
```

#### Results

```
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2020/////07////////10") // nil 
let date2 = dateFormatter.date(from: "2020/07/10") // Jul 10, 2020 at 12:00 AM"
let date3 = dateFormatter.date(from: "2020.07.10") // Jul 10, 2020 at 12:00 AM"
```

Answer (score 0):

I did run your code and it gives `nil`

Whereas if I enter correct date format then I receive the output

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2020-7-10")
print(date) // Optional(2020-07-10 00:00:00 +0000)
```

Comment: hm, I've run author's code and got the result as the author wrote - `Optional(2020-07-09 21:00:00 +0000)` and there is no `nil`

Comment: Yes i also got that result as author said

Comment: @VadimNikolaev i ran it on http://online.swiftplayground.run/ . dint check it in XCode