# iOS: Date not converting correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, datetime-conversion

Say for instance, I have a date: 2014-11-24 12:24:25 stored in an NSString variable.

I'm trying to convert that to an NSDate object so that I can calculate a future date:

```
NSDate *futureTimeStamp;

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];

NSDate *oldDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:timestamp];
```

It keeps telling me that the old date time is: 2014-11-24 06:46:06 +0000 which isn't correct.

Any ideas why it's not converting it correctly?

**Update #1:**

timestamp is a string. Stored in that variable is: 2014-11-24 12:58:40

When I print out oldDate, it shows this in the 2014-11-24 06:58:40 +0000

Comment: Seems like you need to set the date formatter's locale explicitly?

Comment: Post the missing code, for example what exact code tells you what the "old time" is. I bet you are somewhere in India. Maybe the fact that I'm guessing this gives you a hint what you are doing wrong.

Comment: @gnasher729 I'm not in India. lol. I'm in the United States.

Comment: @Jugale I tried adding this: [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]; and it didn't change anything. Same results.

Comment: Does this work? [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"];

Comment: @Pyraego.com Nope. It logs null for the old date using that. =(

Comment: NSDate always dumps in UTC.

Comment: The date conversion is correct. 7 in the morning in London, as the `NSLog()` prints it, is the same time as 1 in the afternoon in Dhaka, where you are.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I'm in the U.S. This date conversion isn't correct.

It should be the exact same date value that is stored in the NSString -- I just need it to be an NSDate object.

Comment: Wherever you are, your device thinks it's in GMT+6. I don't know why, but the problem is the same. The code is functioning as it should.

Comment: NSString *dateStr=[self getUTCFormateDate:[NSDate date]];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss "];
NSDate *dateTodate = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];                                       NSDate* myEvent = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSTimeInterval interval = [dateTodate timeIntervalSinceDate:myEvent];

Comment: Do note that with date format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" you will not be able to parse any times after 12:59:59.

Comment: @HotLicks What do you mean -- time after 12:59:59??

Comment: Like either 13:00:00 or 1:00:00 pm

Comment: @HotLicks I end up taking the string and convert it back to an NSDate before I do any comparisons... so I haven't ran into any issues with parsing because I'm comparing two NSDates... so I don't think I will run into that problem.

Comment: So what happens if you receive a date string with 13:00:00 or 1:00:00 pm in it?  Have you tried it?

Comment: @HotLicks The string is converted to an NSDate object - which prints out 2014-11-25 01:00:00 +0000 for input string 2014-11-25 01:00:00

The 13:00:00 doesn't print out correctly.... I'm curious though if I'll ever get that... because for 12:00 A.M -- it's been 00:00:00.

What are you suggesting should be the format for the datetime stamp?

Comment: So you never have a time of 1 PM?  Always times in the morning?

Comment: @HotLicks That's not what I'm saying. I'm saying it always prints out to the console as the same value as in the morning time. Maybe the reason it does this is because of how I'm storing it in the NSString. What should this yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss so that it keeps AM vs PM?

Comment: Bookmark this: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: @HotLicks I'm beyond confused at this point. If I add 'z' to the end of my date format -- then I get this 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 for the current timestamp... which makes no sense to me.

Comment: Look at what "hh" means.

Comment: @HotLicks OMG! Thank you so very much!!!!

h -> Hour [1-12]. 
H -> Hour [0-23].

Changed format to: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

Comment: And there is a [local "feature"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformatter-locale-feature) you should probably be aware of, when you start testing on real hardware.

Comment: @HotLicks
I'm actually testing on an iPhone 6 device. I had this set in my code: NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];

I"m guessing that is what you are referring to? So, I shouldn't run into any problems, right?

Comment: If you have that (in the right place) you should be OK.

Comment: @HotLicks I have it right after I create my dateFormatter. I haven't run into any problems testing on my device so far. I really appreciate your help! Thank you so much for pointing out the hour issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try converting to the local date from UTC

```
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
  NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:timestamp];
  NSTimeZone *currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
  NSTimeZone *previousTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
  NSInteger currentGMTOffset = [currentTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:date];
  NSInteger currentOffset = [previousTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:date];
  NSTimeInterval gmtInterval = currentGMTOffset - currentOffset;
  NSDate *localDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:gmtInterval sinceDate:date];
```

Comment: This definitely helped me out! Thank you!

Comment: But your date format is wrong.

Comment: And it's bad practice to have an NSDate that is referenced to a timezone other than UTC.  If you do it, comment it up the wazoo.

Comment: @HotLicks The date format matches what the original question was and adding the comments is your opinion! Why the down vote when the answer is correct...

Comment: @HotLicks What should the date format be then??

Comment: Bookmark this: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: And, as I said, never have an NSDate containing other than UTC, and if you break that rule comment the bejeezus out of it.

Comment: @HotLicks I'm confused. I'm comparing two NSDates. I haven't ran into any issues yet... This answer helped me because it showed me how to determine the offset and bring it back to local time -- which is what I needed -- because I needed to compare both NSDates in the same time conversion (local dates).

Comment: @SandyD. - I know you're confused, and getting more confused by the minute.  (You will run into all sorts of "issues" shortly.)

Comment: @HotLicks He is confused by your statement which is your opinion. He stated the answer solved his issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can make time shifting like:

```
NSDate *date = [oldDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:milliseconds];
```

Comment: I'm new to iOS development... so I'm confused how this helps me.. since oldDate is the issue... the oldDate isn't converting from a string to the correct date.

Comment: you can calc the deference between the correct time and the converted date. then you can shift the converted time to correct one.
check this
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html

Comment: The date is correct and does not need to be shifted manually.

Comment: The above solves no problem -- just introduces more.