# Convert a string timezone to NSTimeZone

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I have a time zone formatted like this in an incoming string which I have no control over (it comes in a dictionary from server)

`tzHours = NSString *   @"+01:00"`

But I need to convert it into a `NSTimeZone` so I can format a date

```
NSString *date = [dateDictionary safeObjectForKey:@"date"];
    NSString *time = [dateDictionary safeObjectForKey:@"time"];
    NSString *tzHours = [dateDictionary safeObjectForKey:@"timeZone"];

// Format the date based off the timezone
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [self _apiDateFormatterWithTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
```

But I am unsure how to do this.

Is there a good way to do handle this?

Many thanks

Comment: Would it not just be better to combine the three NSStrings into a single string and use NSDateFormatter on the entire string?

Comment: Pretty sure you'd have to roll your own parser to get the number, then create the timezone with the offset value.

Comment: (`stringsSeparatedByString:@":"`)

Comment: I'm not sure how to cojoin all 3 strings into 1 valid date string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So given you have the three `NSString`s: `date`, `time` and `tzHours`. You could do something like this:

```
NSString *date = @"2015-01-01";
NSString *time = @"14:00:01";
NSString *tzHours = @"+01:00";

NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", date, time, tzHours];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZZ";
dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];

NSDate *dateObject = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

The `dateFormat` of the `NSDateFormatter` naturally depends on the format of `date` and `time`.

Also remember to cache the `NSDateFormatter` or else you will suffer performance-wise.

Comment: In addition, you might want to set the "locale" of the date formatter to "POSIX", to avoid dependencies on the user's regional preferences. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformatter-locale-feature.

Comment: You should be able to use `ZZZZZ` instead of `Z` for the time offset, this parses `-HH:MM` - see [date formats](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns). That avoids having to remove the `:`.

Comment: @CRD: Yes, support for ZZZZZ was added in iOS 6 and OS X 10.8.