# Preferred hour format for locale in date format template

Tags: swift, date, foundation

When generating date formats from a template with Foundation's `DateFormatter` for the Locale "de", like this:

```swift
let locale: Locale = Locale(identifier: "de")
let format = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "dMMMyGhhmmss",
                                      options: 0,
                                      locale: locale)
```

I always get this format:

```
d. MMM y G, h:mm:ss a
```

which renders

```
17. Nov. 2018 n. Chr., 8:30:20 PM
```

The 'PM' part is unusual for Locale "de", but it is my understanding that this method also takes user preferences into account. Is that correct?

I played around with the settings in System Preferences, e.g. switching to 24-hour clock, but nothing I changed had any effect. Do I have to restart something for the changes to take effect?

Can someone explain to me what's going on?

Comment: Change the `h` to `H` in your template.

Comment: @rmaddy Then it also uses the 24-hour format for locale "en". However, your comment prompted me to check the spec again and I found that I could replace `h` with `j`, which causes the format generator to pick `h` or `H` depending on the locale.

Comment: Good find. I always forget about `j`. That should be used with a template like this. You should post your own answer explaining why `j` is the correct solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `h` or `H` in the template, the format will contain the specified hour format (12-hour or 24-hour), regardless of the locale. Use `j` instead. This symbol requests the preferred hour format for the locale.

For example, given the template `dMMMyGjjmmss`, I get:

- `MMM d, y G, h:mm:ss a` (12-hour format) for locale "en"
- `d. MMM y G, HH:mm:ss` (24-hour format) for locale "de"

---

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html) states:

> The format string uses the format patterns from the Unicode Technical Standard #35.

The [Unicode Technical Standard #35](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table) has this to say about the symbol `j`:

> This is a special-purpose symbol. It must not occur in pattern or skeleton data. Instead, it is reserved for use in skeletons passed to APIs doing flexible date pattern generation. In such a context, it requests the preferred hour format for the locale (h, H, K, or k), as determined by whether h, H, K, or k is used in the standard short time format for the locale. In the implementation of such an API, 'j' must be replaced by h, H, K, or k before beginning a match against availableFormats data. Note that use of 'j' in a skeleton passed to an API is the only way to have a skeleton request a locale's preferred time cycle type (12-hour or 24-hour).