# iOS NSDateFormatter behaving differently on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I have the following code to create `NSDate` objects from `NSString` objects.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm aa M/dd/yyyy"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
NSString *day = @"3/26/2015";
NSString *time = @"10:24 PM";
NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", time, day];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

This piece of code works perfectly on the simulator, yielding the exact corresponding time in my time zone. However when I run this on a device with iOS 8, `date` is set to `nil`.

The format I'm using is supposed to work according to [this page](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) that is referenced by this [Apple Developer page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html).

Any help or information on this would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: I'm trying to create NSDate objects from formatted NSString's, not get the date from the system in a predefined fromat. The [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformatter-locale-feature) of this question is probably closely related but I couldn't get the solution to work in my situation.

**Edit 2**: I've just noticed this problem only occurs when 24-Hour Time is enabled in Settings. However, there is no way for me to know which format the device owner is using, so I'm still in need of a solution.

Comment: Have you tried other date formats like yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to deal with the NSDateFormatter locale "feature"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformatter-locale-feature)

Comment: Surely for month you need `MM`? or do you not care about October, November and December?

Comment: Can't replicate in swift, iPhone 6 on iOS 8 and on simulator, it works fine, even with one or two `M`. Do you want the code in swift?

Comment: does one `M` just not care about leading zeros then?

Comment: @Wezly yes, single M doesn't cause a problem in this situation. I've tried it on the simulator.

Comment: I have further information on the problem, please see my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with such strict date formats, you need to set the locale to avoid having issues with the device current locale when formatting dates. Otherwise, the `NSDateFormatter` will use the device's locale, which explains the fact that it happens only when you enable 24-Hour Time in Settings.

See [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html):

> In all cases, you should consider that formatters default to using the user’s locale ([`currentLocale`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSLocale/currentLocale)) superimposed with the user’s preference settings. If you want to use the user’s locale but without their individual settings, you can get the locale id from the current user locale ([`localeIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSLocale/localeIdentifier)) and make a new "standard” locale with that, then set the standard locale as the formatter's [locale](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateFormatter/locale).

For example, in your case, you could use the `en_US_POSIX`:

```
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
dateFormatter.locale = enUSPOSIXLocale;
```