# Parsing time string into NSDate returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have time portion as a string and I want to parse it into date, as I have concern about the time portion of date. But when I parse it with the given format, result is nil. How should I parse my *Time String*?

**Time String:** 23:59

**Method:**

```
+(NSDate*)getDateFromStringProfile:(NSString*)strDate
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:timeZone];


    NSDate *result =[dateFormat dateFromString:strDate];
    return result;
}
```

**Result:** nil

Comment: Try setting the locale with `NSLocale` for the `NSDataFormatter`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformatter-locale-feature

Answer (score 0):

Adding the locale worked for me. I added the following locale.

```
[dateFormat setLocale: [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
```

And I got a NSDate object instead of nil. Thanks for comment @ZaneHelton

Comment: You should use en_US_POSIX.