# Why is NSFormatter dateFromString occasionally returning nil?

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nslocale

I have a method to convert a string in a specific format into an `NSDate` but it occasionally returns nil.

```
- (NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)dateAndTime
{
    NSDate *date;

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"];

    NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
    [formatter setTimeZone:gmt];

    date = [formatter dateFromString:dateAndTime];

    return date;
}
```

This works most of the time from what I can tell, but there's a percentage of time that it fails.

I've been tracking this bug for a while so there is some code that makes the app crash when this happens. The crash reports tell me the values that made the method return nil.

For example, I received a crash report telling me that "4/14/2015 7:35 PM" returned nil.

When I hard code the same value for every date, it works when running the app in debug mode from my computer.

What could be going on here? Am I not covering some cases for `NSDate`s? How come it doesn't happen on every device?

Comment: "4/14/2014" does not match "MM/dd/yyyy". "04/14/2014" would match. You also need to set the locale to "en_US_POSIX". The need for that is covered in many discussions here and in Apple's documentation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformatter-locale-feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the date string of `4/14/2015 7:35 PM` is possibly `M/d/yyyy h:m a` or `M/dd/yyyy h:mm a`.
http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Second, it is recommended to set NSLocale to NSDateFormatter.

```
formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
```

I had a same issue that NSDate was set `nil` when I worked with a Chinese guy. It happened only on the specific devices, and the problem was region settings.

To reproduce the problem, follow below steps:

1. go to Settings app
2. General -> Language & Region -> Advanced
3. Turn off Automatic
4. change Language to `Chinese, Simplified`
5. execute your app again. You will find NSDate is always nil if NSLocale is NOT set.

Comment: The locale needs to be "en_US_POSIX", not just "en_US".

Comment: Yep - I was able to reproduce the issue with your suggestions. The only thing I'm not really clear on (even after the doc you posted) is the difference between M and MM. The app seems to be working now that I set the locale, regardless of using MM.