# NSDateFormatter returns unexpected nil

Tags: swift, cocoa, foundation

I'm trying to use `NSDateFormatter` to get the NSDate from String.

I've got the date in this format `"Sat, 01 Aug 2015 15:00:12 GMT"` and I'm setting date format this way:

`dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"`

but `dateFormatter.dateFromString("Sat, 01 Aug 2015 15:00:12 GMT")` returns nil. Why is that happening and how to fix it?

EDIT:

`var date:NSDate?
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"
date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("Sat, 01 Aug 2015 15:00:12 GMT")`

Comment: As explained in the referenced thread, you have to set the date formatters locale to "en_US_POSIX". See also [What is the best way to deal with the NSDateFormatter locale “feature”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformatter-locale-feature) and [Technical Q&A QA1480
NSDateFormatter and Internet Dates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html).

Comment: I verified that before closing the question as a duplicate :)