# NSDate conversion to NSString doesn't follow NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have problems with NSDate to NSString conversion, I have the following code in a method

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
[formatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'zzz'"];
return [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

If I´m not mistaken this should return a String like

```
"2016-01-15T22:45:40.GMT"
```

But the resulting string depends on the device configuration, meaning if the device shows the date as 24 hour then i get the result above, on the other hand if the device is configured to show the house as A.M. P.M. then I get

```
"2016-01-15T10:46:50 p.m..GMT"
```

Comment: You probably need to set the locale: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6613110/3985749) for details.

Comment: Above answer is nice because you can reuse it easier. But if you don't want to create category, you could set formatter's locale like this formatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];

Comment: FYI - you don't need to escape all of the punctuation. Your format can be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.zzz`. Note you do need to escape the `T`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1)

> Although in principle a format string specifies a fixed format, by default NSDateFormatter still takes the user’s preferences (including the locale setting) into account. You must consider the following points when using format strings:
>
> In iOS, the user can override the default AM/PM versus 24-hour time setting. This may cause NSDateFormatter to rewrite the format string you set.

<del>I think you'll have to consider using your own formatting method if you want the result to have a fixed format, regardless of user settings.</del>

Actually, [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6735644/2976878) (as pointed out by [pbasdf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3985749/pbasdf)), it appears that you can circumvent this by simply setting the locale:

```
NSLocale* en_US_POSIX = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[formatter setLocale:en_US_POSIX];
```