# NSDateFormatter return nil in IOS10

Tags: ios, swift, ios10

The following code crashes in XCode 8 when running on iOS 10 (does not crash on previous iOS versions):

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS'Z'"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()


let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2016-09-04T08:32:46.195514289Z")!
```

The crash happens because the date formatter returns nil. I tried playing and changing the dateFormat but the result is always nil. Did something change in iOS 10?

EDIT: same code works in Storyboard when running with Swift 3. It seems that the issue happens with Swift 2.3 and iOS 10

Comment: Cannot reproduce. However, when working with fixed date formats, it is always a good idea to set the locale to "en_US_POSIX" and not to the current locale. That might solve your problem.

Comment: With respect to the current answers: Please note that "it works for me" is not considered an acceptable answer, compare http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277923/are-your-code-works-fine-for-me-answers-acceptable.

Comment: Even with Swift 2.3 I cannot reproduce. Have you tried the POSIX locale?

Comment: @MartinR Yep, setting locale to POSIX did the trick :). Thanks!

Comment: I also have this issue (with a single user on iOS 10.2) - how do I set the locale to POSIX?

Comment: This category seems to offer a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformatter-locale-feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me. Although I am using Swift 3:

```
let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS'Z'"
df.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
df.locale = NSLocale.current
let date = df.date(from: "2016-09-04T08:32:46.195514289Z")
print("date: \(date)")
```

Prints:

```
date: Optional(2016-09-04 08:32:46 +0000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code in a Playground (had to convert it to Swift 3 to do this) and it worked. But I noticed, that in Swift 3, the timeZone is initialized like this:

```
TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
```

This initializer is also available in [NSTimeZone](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nstimezone/1387248-init), which you can use in Swift 2.x. According to Apple's documentation, this would be the correct initializer, when you use something like "UTC" or "GMT" as name. I'm not sure, what we are supposed to do with `init(name:)`

Comment: @MartinR I'm saying that it worked in Swift 3 and provided a possible solution for Swift 2.x. In my opinion, this is not simply saying: "it works for me"