# NSDateFormatter- dateFromString returning nil when set AM/PM

Tags: ios

I have the following string `2016-10-26T16:01:18.361Z` and works with the folowing code:

```
formater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formater setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
[formater setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
```

But using the same `string` and the same `formater` is returning nil when system clock settings is changed to AM/PM

What format should I use?

Comment: Unrelated but do NOT quote the `Z` in your format string. It should be `@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"`.

Comment: That's why I said my comment wasn't related to your immediate issue. That will be solved by setting the formatter's locale to `en_US_POSIX`.

Comment: Wow you are right, but why!?

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformatter-locale-feature

Comment: That code works just fine for me on the simulator when it's set to AM/PM mode.

Comment: I had test on iPhone 6 and 6S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rmaddy said this code works fine.

```
formater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formater setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
[formater setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
[formater setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
```