# Does it make sense to use locale and dateFormat together for NSDateFormatter?

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

So does it make sense? I think dateFormat itself specify exactly the output, isn't it?

Comment: Please clarify your question. It's unclear. And when you say "local" do you actually mean "locale"?

Comment: Sorry, yes, `locale`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to parse a date you can use both at the same time:

```
let formater = DateFormatter()
let enDateString = "2019, 16 January"
formater.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
formater.dateFormat = "yyyy, dd MMMM"

let enDate = formater.date(from: enDateString)
print(enDate) // display: Optional(2019-01-16 00:00:00 +0000)

let frDateString = "16 janvier 2019"
formater.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr_FR")
formater.dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy"

let frDate = formater.date(from: frDateString)
print(frDate) // display: Optional(2019-01-16 00:00:00 +0000)
```

Here the `MMMM` pattern in the `dateFormat` allows you to parse the month in plain text in the targeted `locale`.

Comment: You should never use `dateFormat` when showing a date to a user, regardless of locale. Use `dateStyle` and `timeStyle`. Setting a locale and using `dateFormat` is largely a contradiction. Only used `dateFormat` when you need to parse a fixed format date string or you need to generate a fixed format string to send to a server or something similar.

Comment: Do you know, does it make sense to use for this string `local`? There is no month in plain text or similar here, only digits: `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm`

Comment: @János When you use a fixed format like that, you need to use the special locale of `en_US_POSIX`.

Comment: Hi @rmaddy! Why?

Comment: @János See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformatter-locale-feechur?rq=1